# C socket programming in LInux, double free corruption (fasttop) error

Tags: c, linux, sockets, free, corruption

I've read answers to other similar questions, but none of them seemd to resolve my problem.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
  pthread_t thread_id;
  int sockfd;
} client_t;

client_t *clients;
size_t client_n = 0;

void *client_thread(void *client_ptr) {
  client_t client = *(client_t*) client_ptr;
  char buffer[500];
  int state;
  while(1) {
    state = send(client.sockfd, 0, 1, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    if(state == -1) {
      printf("socket-%d closed\n", client.sockfd);
      break;
    }

    read(client.sockfd, buffer, 500);
    printf("from socket-%d: %s\n", client.sockfd, buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, 500);
  }
  close(client.sockfd);
  free(client_ptr);
  client_n--;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen;
  struct sockaddr_in clientaddr, serveraddr;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(8080);

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  listen(sockfd, 5);

  clilen = sizeof(clientaddr);

  clients = (client_t*) malloc(sizeof(client_t));

  while(1) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientaddr, &clilen);
    printf("New connection: socket-%d\n", newsockfd);
    clients = (client_t*) realloc(clients, (client_n + 1) * sizeof(client_t));
    clients[client_n].sockfd = newsockfd;
    pthread_create(&clients[client_n].thread_id, NULL, client_thread, (void*) &clients[client_n]);
    client_n++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program should listen for incoming connections and then create a new thread for each. The program will then handle each single client simultaneously. Since this should be the core of a game server, i created a structure to contain each players information.

It all worked fine untill i added the:

```
close(client.sockfd);
  free(client_ptr);
  client_n--;
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Your allocation is broken. You allocate an array of `client_t` but try to free a single entry, that is not possible. Just allocate a single entry each time, give it to the client thread which will be able to free it.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
free(client_ptr);
client_n--;
```

there are *two* problems.

The first is the `free` call. You didn't actually call `malloc` (or `realloc` or `calloc`) for `client_ptr`. Instead `client_ptr` is pointing into *an array* that you allocated dynamically, but the element pointed to by `client_ptr` wasn't itself allocated dynamically separately. That leads to *undefined behavior* when you pass a pointer to `free` that wasn't actually allocated with `malloc` and family. ***Except*** for the very first element (i.e. `clients[0]`), when you instead free the whole array. The solution to this is to simply not call `free` in the thread.

The other problem is with the `client_n--` expression. You don't protect this (or the corresponding `client_n++` in the `main` function) from modification by other threads. That means two or more threads could possibly modify this simultaneously again leading to *undefined behavior*. You need to have a semaphore or mutex to protect this modification.

---

There are also a couple of other problems. For example you don't join the threads that have ended, leading to resource leaks. You don't check for errors or closed connection from the `read` call (a nicely closed connection is reported by the `read` call returning `0`).